# JSON.serialize() Map<String, Object> changes Map structure

Tags: json, deserialize, serialize

I have a `Map<String,Object>()` which I am trying to store in a text field for a subsequent asynchronous operation. My idea was for the following async operation to query for this map and re-use it.

I tried using JSON.serialize() for this purpose like so:

`MyObj__c.MyField__c = JSON.serialize(myMap);`

Then the async job would pick up the value of `MyField__c` and deserialize it like so:

`Map<String, Object> myRestoredMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(myObj.MyField__c);`

However I found some discrepancies when system.debugging `myMap` and `myRestoredMap`.

Portion of `myMap` when system.debugged:

> ...detail=Account:{HealthCloudGA__SourceSystemId__c=123,
> Name=SomeName, RecordTypeId=012Ot0000002NR5IAM}...

Same portion but in `myRestoredMap`:

> ...detail={HealthCloudGA__SourceSystemId__c=123, Name=SomeName, > RecordTypeId=012Ot0000002NR5IAM, attributes={type=Account}...

I can see that serializing the map adds "attributes={type=Account}". How can I preserve the original state of the map?

Comment: Serializing _anything_ that is/contains an SObject will cause that additional metadata to appear. It shouldn't present any trouble when you go to deserialize untyped (nor if you deserialize as a `Map<Id, SObject>`, which would probably end up being easier/less typing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON doesn't know about Apex data types. The JSON library in Apex, therefore, has to be told if you want to use a specific DTO-like object. For example, if all the attributes were sObject entries, you could `JSON.deserialize(someString, Map<String, sObject>.class)` to get a map that contained records. In this case, the attributes property would be consumed to coerce each value into an sObject of the appropriate concrete type. In fact, if I were going to do what you're trying to do, I would indeed wrap the entire record into a map.

```
record.MyField__c = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, sObject> { 'record' => record });
```

Then for deserialization, I can use a helper class:

```
class RecordWrapper {
  sObject record;
}
```

...

```
RecordWrapper wrapper = (RecordWrapper)JSON.deserialize(record.MyField__c, RecordWrapper.class);
```

This will perfectly rehydrate all of your data in the asynchronous process.

Alternatively, you may want to create a wrapper that you serialize with, rather than using `myMap`. When you use a generic map, you get the default generic behavior, which may also be contributing to your problem. I strong recommend using a class to serialize/deserialize your data for repeatable results.